# Webpack/ts-loader import with .js extension not resolving

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

My directory structure is as follows:

```
projectRoot
├── project-server
│   ├── src
│   └── pom.xml
├── project-ui
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── src
│       └── file.ts.  (imports ./file.js)
```

My problem is that `project-server` uses the transpiled js files and such needs the `.js` extension to resolve the files. I'm using webpack-dev-server for development and using `ts-loader` but I'm getting the error that:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './file.js' in 
'/projectRoot/project-ui/src'
```

The following is my `webpack.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './project-ui/src/file1.ts',
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      ... other rules
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
  }
```

My `tsconfig.json` has configuration specific to where `project-server` needs the js files. Namely,
`"outDir": "../project-server/src/main/resources/static"`

So I'm unsure how to configure Webpack/ts-loader to correctly resolve the import statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ts-loader doesn't natively support having imports with a .js extension so this project https://github.com/softwareventures/resolve-typescript-plugin provides the extra step required to make this work.

Comment: Somewhat related to extension handling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71544906/2954288 and the links therein.

Answer (score 6):

## Update as of 2022-10-20

[Webpack v5.74.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.74.0) was released in July 2022, and it includes a new [`resolve.extensionAlias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensionalias) option which provides a solution to this problem.

For example:

```js
resolve: {
    extensionAlias: {
        '.js': ['.js', '.ts'],
    },
}
```

---

### Answer as at 2021-09-01

I'm dealing with basically the same issue at the moment. I'm afraid I don't have a good answer for you, though I have found a discussion from 2017 that said ts-loader doesn't support this behaviour:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577#issuecomment-343649391

If support has been added since then, I haven't been able to find any details on it yet.

I have had some success though with setting up aliases in my `webpack.config.js`'s `resolve.alias` section, so relative paths to certain files using `.js` are resolved by Webpack to the `.ts` equivalents. For example:

```
alias: {
    './file-processing.js': './file-processing.ts',
},
```

But this is a very clunky solution that's not at all scalable.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful to you but there was discussion about this in the TypeStrong repo to allow imports to have a .js extension https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/465#issuecomment-909445205 and commenters are saying that this project https://github.com/softwareventures/resolve-typescript-plugin provides the extra step to allow it to work.

Comment: Thanks @amosq, that discussion is about exactly the issue I'm running into but I hadn't found it despite days of searching for a solution, and it definitely looks useful (and it's something of a relief to see that I'm not the only person running into this problem). I see that suggestion you mentioned only popped up a couple of days ago. I'll give that `resolve-typescript-plugin` a go and report back once I've been able to try it out.

Comment: Thanks again @amosq, I've just tried that plugin and it has solved this problem for me. If you'd like to add it as an answer instead of a comment I'd be happy to mark it as the accepted answer. If not I'll add it myself tomorrow for anyone else who runs across this question.

Comment: Sorry, I was clearly lost when I posted that last comment. I thought this discussion was on [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008462/importing-es-modules-for-typescript-webpack-and-jasmine), instead of my response to this question. Oops!

Comment: I'm back to working on the project where I had this issue and I'm trying the plugin, however I'm getting a segfault when I try to launch webpack. Could you possibly link your webpack config and/or your package.json?

Comment: Here's a link to my base project on GitHub @amosq: [base-package](https://github.com/cipscis/base-package)