# Mapping a relative path import to the right `@types` in Typescript

Tags: typescript, d3.js, es6-modules

At runtime, for the browser, I need

```
import * as d3 from '../lib/d3.js';
```

to correctly fetch `d3`. I verified that this does work indeed. But the file containing the above, call it `main.js`, is generated from a typescript file `main.ts` which currently starts with the very same line above.

The typescript compiler complains that it cannot find the module or its declarations. I thought to fix this with something along the lines of

```json
  "paths": {
     "../lib/d3.js": ["node_modules/@types/d3"]
  },
```

but from the Typescript handbook I cannot see how to write this correctly: shall the key be the full file path or just a module name? What about the value array: file paths, directories?

Can this be done with path mapping in tsconfig.json at all? (I know how to get this going with webpack, but I am now interested to know how to do without.)

Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37971, but does not help me.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use a bundler like webpack or rollup

Answer (score 3):

According to the following reasoning, what the OP wants cannot be done as of March 2022:

1. In the browser, [imports of modules **must** be a relative or absolute path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#importing_features_into_your_script): "In some module systems, you can omit the file extension and the leading /, ./, or ../ (e.g. 'modules/square'). This doesn't work in native JavaScript modules."
2. According to a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577#issuecomment-754941937) on a very old Typescript issue, the compiler does not rewrite import paths, ever.
3. The [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#relative-vs-non-relative-module-imports) says: "A relative import is resolved relative to the importing file and cannot resolve to an ambient module declaration.

So the first two require to write the exact relative path import statement into the `.ts` file that will be understood by the browser, while the third statement says that we cannot re-map these relative paths for the compiler to find declarations.

Bottom line: there is no way without a bundler as soon as we (a) use a Javascript library with a `.d.ts` and (b) target a browser.

Late addition (2022-09): Webpack has its own issues with `.js` imports for Typescript that need to be solved with yet another plugin, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050859/2954288).

Later addition (2024-01): If the import can use an absolute path (as opposed to what the OP requires), say `/foo/bla/d3.js` which works on the server, i.e. the library gets copied there by whatever means during installation, then [`compileroptions.paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) can be used to map that path elsewhere during compilation, for example into `node_modules`. But, well, for anything but a single library with no dependencies a bundler should be used (webpack, rollup, esbuild, ...).

Comment: Can't help to wonder whether (3) is cast in stone. Asking the compiler to map a relative path like `./lib/d3.js` to some `.../d3/index.d.ts` does not seem that far out. There is for sure an issue already ... (off to find it).